# How to create light system font with special font attributes

Tags: ios, uifont

I need to create a UIFont which is:

1. San Francisco
2. Light weight
3. Using the case insensitive font attribute (to display the '/' glyph vertically aligned to numbers)

I am using this code to go about it:

```
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
NSArray *additionalFontSettings = @[@{UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kCaseSensitiveLayoutType), UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @(kCaseSensitiveLayoutOnSelector)}];
fontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:@{UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: additionalFontSettings, UIFontDescriptorTraitsAttribute: @{UIFontWeightTrait : @(UIFontWeightLight)}}];
return [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:50];
```

I get the right font with the right feature enabled, but I can't get the font weight to be adhered to. I need the light weight of the system font. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of starting with `preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle`, what if you start with `systemFontOfSize:weight:`?

Comment: @matt that method is only available on `UIFont`, not `UIFontDescriptor`.

Comment: I know that. That is my point.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to add my required font feature without using `UIFontDescriptor`?

Comment: I didn't say don't use font descriptor. I said _start_ with the font.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Matt was right with his hint. I had forgotten that you can derive a `UIFontDescriptor` from an existing `UIFont`.

Therefore, creating the descriptor like so works:

```
UIFont *lightFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50 weight:UIFontWeightLight];
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = lightFont.fontDescriptor;
```